# Sauce Labs Session ID with Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, saucelabs

There is an easy way to get the Sauce Labs job ID when using Selenium-Webdriver as outlined at the bottom of [this page](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Ruby+Test+Setup+Example).

Is there a similar method for Watir-Webdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver session ID is not directly exposed via the Watir API. However, you can just call the same method directly against the underlying driver object:

Assuming `browser` is your Watir::Browser instance:

```
browser.driver.session_id
```

Comment: I was working on this yesterday and tried that. I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `session_id' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x000000031b2bc0>` with your solution (using Chrome). When I type `browser.driver.session_storage` I see `@session_id` in there, but I couldn't figure out how to extract it.

Comment: I should also mention that I was using a page from your website as my guide yesterday (https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/accessing-selenium-webdriver-from-watir-webdriver/). Thanks!

Comment: When you say you are using Chrome, do you mean Chrome locally or a remote instance - ie `Watir::Browser.new :chrome` or `Watir::Browser.new :remote`? I believe `session_id` is only available to the remote driver ([see the change log](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/CHANGES#L284-L295)).

Comment: Yep, I was using `Watir::Browser.new :chrome`. Thanks!